# Photon absorption and emission in 2nd quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, photons, solid-state-physics, second-quantization

I am looking for models which describe the interaction of matter (lets take a 1D chain of atoms) with photons, especially the emission and absorption. I would love to see the derivation of models in the language of 2nd quantization with a Hubbard like interaction between the electrons.

So I think I am looking for the derivation of models similar to the Hubbard-Holstein model, which describes the interaction of phonons with electrons (but I want photons not phonons).

Are those models analytically solvable? If not, what methods are used to solve them?

Comment: The standard reference to study the interaction of photons with (extended) particles, both on a classical and quantum standpoint is this book by [Spohn](http://www.amazon.com/Dynamics-Charged-Particles-their-Radiation/dp/0521037077). The quantum model is called, especially in the mathematical physics literature, the Pauli-Fierz Hamiltonian. You can modify it so that it contains a particle-particle interaction as well.

Comment: @yuggib: I think that qualifies as an answer, if you expanded a bit.

Comment: @ACuriousMind But then I would have to write down explicitly the Hamiltonian, and the Pauli-Fierz Hamiltonian is extremely unpleasant to write... :-P If I had time tonight or tomorrow I will

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that the Pauli-Fierz Hamiltonian is a qunatized version of the Abraham model and hence assumes the electron to have a rigid shell? This seems odd.